# question about convergence in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

For the following question:

Let $X$ be an infinite cofinite soace, and let $y$ be a one to one sequence in $X$.  Show that $y_n\rightarrow x$ for all $x\in X$.

What I want to ask is, why does the sequence need to be one to one?  I mean is it absolutely necessary that the sequence be one to one.  I am not sure if the notion of being surjective can be used to characterise a sequence.  IF so, how would it precesiely be formulated.  Also how will that affect convergence.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't need to be $1$-$1$, but it does need to be eventually $1$-$1$.  In other words, if any member of the sequence is repeated infinitely often, the result doesn't hold.

Comment: @RobertShore when you mean eventually 1-1, does it mean that the  terms m-tail of the sequence has to be one to one?  Also, if we have a sequence that it repeats infinitely often, does that imply it has two different tail sequences.  Where as a convergent sequence only contains one.

Comment: Actually, I'm just wrong.  The sequence $\{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 \ldots \}$ works in the cofinite topology on $\Bbb R$.  What you need is that no element repeats infinitely often.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence converges to $x$ if every neighborhoods of $x$ contains all but finitely many members of the sequence.  A neighborhood of any point $x \in X$ contains all but finitely many points of $X$, so if no elements of the sequence repeat, every neighborhood of $x$ must contain all but finitely many points of the sequence.  But if any element of the sequence repeats the value $y$ infinitely often and $x \neq y$, then $X \setminus \{ y \}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ with infinitely many members of the sequence outside the neighborhood.

So you don't need the sequence to be $1$-$1$, but you do need that the sequence doesn't repeat any entry infinitely often.

Comment: isn't saying that a sequence not repeating any term infinitely often is the same as saying that the sequence is one to one.  Since, not repeating a term infinitely often eliminate the possibility of have terms in the $m$-tail of the sequence being repeated finitely many times.  Maybe I am missing the subtle differences between having a sequence not being one to one and a sequence having its terms repeated infinitely many times

Comment: One last thing, when you say that in the cofinite topology, if a sequence converges to every point in which all neighborhood contain $x$, does this mean the cofinite topology is not hausdorff because any sequence in it doesn't converge to a unique point?

Comment: @SethMai The cofinite topology of an infinite space is not Hausdorff, as you can prove directly from the usual definition of Hausdorff.  The sequence $\{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 \ldots \}$ is not $1$-$1$, nor is any tail of the sequence, but it doesn't repeat any entry infinitely often.

Answer (score 0):

One to one is to simplify the statement. What you want to avoid, is that the sequence is eventually constant (with some value $p$, say) because for such a  sequence the statement does not hold, as $y_n \to p$ only, and $y_n \not \to q$ for $p \neq q$, as $U:=X\setminus \{p\}$ is then a neighbourhood of $q$ such that no tail of the sequence lies in $U$. So such a sequence does not converge to all points of the set. Similarly, for a sequence that has a tail like $p,q,p,q,p,q,\ldots$ alternately we can say that it does not converge to $p$, nor to $q$ nor to any other point of $X$ (using neighbourhoods like $X\setminus \{p\}$ and $X\setminus \{q\}$ or $X\setminus \{p,q\}$ depending).

So you can get away with weaker than 1-1, we just need that no tail contains infinitely many equal terms, or equivalently, no value is assumed by infinitely many terms of the sequence. (In the beginning we could have some duplicate terms, but what matters happens in the tail.) But it's certainly true for 1-1 sequences (so when $y_n \neq y_m$ whenever $n \neq m$). And it's a nice and short statement. Good for shock value in a classroom: $\frac{1}{n}$ in $\Bbb R$ in the cofinite topology converges to $\pi$, etc...(!) It illustrates that we cannot always say that $x$ is **the** limit of a sequence (we can just say **a** limit), and for many sequences in this space there are infinitely many limits. It's to make you aware of your "intuition", which can be misleading..

Comment: is there a technical term in math for something that is weaker than one to one?  Also, in the case of cofinite topology, any open set that contains all but finitely many terms of a converging sequence, converges to all the values in a neigborhood which contains them.  Is this another way of saying tge cofinite topology is not Hausdorff?

Comment: @SethMai finite-to-one is one way of putting it. An open set does not converge to anything so the second statement makes no sense. That the cofinite topology is not Hausdorff is just clear from the fact that any two non-empty open subsets intersect so the definition of Hausdorff suffices. It's almost *anti*-Hausdorff that way. There are spaces where sequences have unique limits (if they converge at all, then to at most one point) but are not Hausdorff. Sequences do not in general suffice to demonstrate Hausdorffness, though a single sequence with two distinct limits does refute Hausdorffness.